# Is it possible to change facebook profile picture link?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

A Facebook page profile picture links to the gallery by default.

Is it possible to change this link to say "a custom tab?" or anything?

Comment: Can you explain a little more what you want to do? It will help us to answer your question more specifically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not currently supported